# Question concerning half-angle results

Tags: trigonometry

If someone could kindly read through this page (this is S.L. Loney's book on Plane Trigonometry):[image]

I find trouble following a cetain leap here. Why is it true that a formula which gives us $cos$$A\over2$ in terms of $cosA$, should also give us $cos$$2n\pi \pm A \over2$? I certainly know that the two expressions aren't identical. Hence if someone could explain the reasoning behind this, it would be of much help. Thank you in adance.

Answer (score 1):

The $sin$ and $cos$ functions are periodic, with a period of $2 \pi$. These functions applied to an angle $A$ will yield the exact same value when applied to an angle $A+2n\pi$, since that represents the same location on the unit circle, just having gone around fully $n$ extra times. Adding complete rotations (integer multiples of $2\pi$) doesn't change anything in a trig problem. The $sin$ or $cos$ of an angle does not change when adding/subtracting an integer multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Correct, but then that would mean that $cos$$A\over2$ is identical with $cos$$2n\pi \pm$$A\over2$, but certainly not the same as the result provided in the book, which is $cos($$2n\pi \pm A \over 2$$)$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula doesn't 'perceive' that the number you give it, let's call it $x$, is equal to $\cos A$. It just knows $x$ is $x$. In particular, $\cos A=\cos(2\pi n\pm A$) for any integer $n$. If you give the formula $x=\cos(A)=\cos(2\pi n\pm A)$, it should return the cosine of the half angle of both. After all, the formula's job is to take $x$ in and spit out the number $y$ where $y=\cos(\theta/2)$ for $x=\cos(\theta)$. As $\theta$ is not uniquely determined, but any formula necessarily uniquely determines a value $y$, there is a problem!

---

Let $f$ be a universal formula. That means, $f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ and $x=\cos(\theta)\implies f(x)=\cos(\theta/2)$, for arbitrary $\theta\in\Bbb R$. We want to show no such function exists. Note that the same function but for the double angle, that *does* exist! We check $f$ doesn't exist just by letting $\theta=A$ and letting $\theta=2\pi+A$, and letting $x=\cos(A)=\cos(2\pi+A)$. The property of $f$ says that $y=f(x)=f(\cos(A))$ implies $y=\cos(A/2)$. However, $y=f(x)=f(\cos(2\pi+A))$ implies $y=\cos(\pi+A/2)=-\cos(A/2)$ *also* holds. Therefore, this property of $f$ implies $\cos(A/2)=y=-\cos(A/2)$ which is obviously false for generic $A$.

Comment: It appears to me you may have missed my question. What misleads me is the part where $cos($$2n\pi \pm A \over 2$$)$ is equal to $cos$$A\over2$. This is seemingly not the case, because $cos$$A\over2$ is equal to $cos($$2n\pi \pm$$A\over2$$)$

Comment: @Camelot823 I think you've missed my answer. $2\pi n\pm A$ is just some angle, $\theta_1$. $A$ is also just some angle, $\theta_2$. Let $x=\cos(\theta_1)=\cos(\theta_2)=\cos(\theta)$ (for any other $\theta$). If $f$ is a half-angle formula, $f(x)$ must return a unique number $y$, where $y=\cos(\theta/2)$ if $x=\cos(\theta)$. So, we try this for both $\theta=\theta_1$ and $\theta=\theta_2$. Unfortunately, we find two different values of $y$, so no uniquely determined half-angle formula can exist

Comment: The whole point is that $\cos\frac{2\pi n\pm A}{2}$ is not equal to $\cos(A/2)$. However, from the perspective of some universal half-angle formula, they should be. That is proof no perfect half-angle formula exists

Comment: Hold on, from the perspective of some universal half-angle formula, why exactly should they be? That's the point I'm not getting initially. Assuming that some universal half-angle formula does indeed exist, that is that each cosine of an angle $A$ has a *unique* cosine $A\over2$. Why does that mean that  $cos$$2πn±A\over2$ is equal to $cos$$A\over2$?

Comment: @Camelot823 I've elaborated

Comment: Ah, now that you've properly demonstrated it, I believe I've understood it exceptionally. I should think about this myself with a pen and paper. Thank you much for elaborating, this conversation really helped me a lot!